# Bottom border lines add if table has multiple rows

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I want to add bottom border lines if table has multiple rows. If table has only single row then bottom border should be hidden. Please guide how can I accomplish this. Please see the example image below.

[image]

Comment: please share your html and css

Comment: You could use a selector like `table > tbody > tr:not(:last-of-type)` and give that a bottom border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `last-of-type` or `last-child` as @David said, here for example

```
table tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
}

table tr:last-of-type td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9muS/)

Comment: @AwaisImran you welcome, also the above selectors are general so if you are targeting specific table than make sure you use class or a wrapper class like `.wrap table tr td {}`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to select the `tr:last-child` that is a sibling of a previous `tr`:

```
tr + tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

The above assumes (from the look of your picture) that the `border-bottom` is on the `td`, if it's on the `tr` itself, though:

```
tr + tr:last-child {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

If the `border-bottom` is on the `table` itself, then JavaScript will be necessary (since CSS has no parent-selector), since you offer jQuery as a tag to your question:

```
$('table').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('tr').length < 2;
}).addClass('singleOrNoRows');
```

With the CSS:

```
.singleOrNoRows {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVP9T/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">sadfs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">sdaf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">sdaf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">sadf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
body {
    font:normal 12px/17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#666666;
    }
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    }
.wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
table,thead,tbody,th,td,tr { 
    display: block;
    background-color:#f9f5f5;
}
table thead tr { 
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

table td { 
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0; 
    margin:0 10px;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
table tr:last-of-type td {
    border-bottom:0;
    }
```